# Label not displaying value dynamic checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

[image]I have an array that I am using to create checkboxes dynamically. The checkboxes are are appearing but not the label values. How can I get the label values to show?

There is currently only one item in the array and that is working properly as one checkbox is loading. The label value is not coming through. (see attached screenshot)

```
for (var value of uniquePackageStatuses) {
    $('#packageStatusCheckboxes')
        .append(`<input type="checkbox" id="${value}" name="status" value="${value}">`)
        .append(`<label for="${value}">${value}</label></div>`)
}
```

Comment: When you check the inspector do you see the `label` element at all?

Comment: @displacedtexan Yes the label element is there I have added a screenshot of the inspector above.

Comment: it looks like "${value}" isn't coming through. The checkbox `id` is blank, and so is the input `for`. I haven't used jquery much so I'm not sure I can help more than that, but check into the template literals since that looks like it could be the issue.

Comment: Actually switching the quotation marks to something like "<input type='checkbox' id=`${value}`...>" might do it

Comment: @displacedtexan, no; it's a template literal string, the back-ticks are required for the `${value}` to interpolate the value of the variable into the string. Though obviously the problem is with that variable's value.

Comment: Yep, I know that (see my comment above where I used the term) ;) the formatting is stripping them out and I'm sure OP knows since they used them originally.

ETA: also in the original code OP does *not* use template literals in the "${value}" block, which is the point I'm making. ;)